# ListViews with the same View

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have some `ListView` and I want that they all have the same `View`. So, if the following is my `View`:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Game Name" 
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GameName}"  />
      <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Creator"  
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Creator}" />
      <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Publisher" 
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

I want something like this:

```
<Grid>

 <ListView>
   <!--Here my ListView is the same defined above-->
 </ListView>

 <ListView>
   <!--Here my ListView is the same defined above-->
 </ListView>

</Grid>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define view in resources (either in  resource dictionary of top-level control, or in external resource dictionary):

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <GridView x:Key="myView" x:Shared="false">
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Game Name" 
     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GameName}"  />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Creator"  
     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Creator}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Publisher" 
     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher}" />
        </GridView>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ListView View="{StaticResource myView}"/>
    <ListView View="{StaticResource myView}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: @gliderkite: what are exception details?

Comment: `Can not convert the value in the 'View' in an object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ViewBase'. Impossible to share the viualization in more than one ListView.`

Comment: @gliderkite: sorry, I'll fix the answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Cheers

```
<Grid>

    <ListView Name="FirstList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Game Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GameName}"  />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Creator" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Creator}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Publisher" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <ListView View="{Binding Path=View, ElementName=FirstList}" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: Binding View? What does it means?

Comment: See the update. By the way, default property for Binding expression is the Path property. Cheers